# Cypher request via Rest returns 400 Bad Request, why?

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, jersey

I tried a simple cypher rest request. But I get a 400 Bad Request as response. The request output seems to be ok. What's wrong?

```
public class HelloRest {
  public static String SERVER_ROOT_URI = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = Client.create();
    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
    WebResource cypher = client.resource(SERVER_ROOT_URI + "cypher");
    String request = "{\"query\":\"MATCH (n) RETURN n\"}";
    ClientResponse cypherResponse = cypher.post(ClientResponse.class, request);
    System.out.println(cypherResponse);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `application/json` for `Accept` and `Content-Type` HTTP headers. If that does not help, please dump the full request and full response and attach them to your question.

Comment: I thought I tried that before without success, but now it works. Thanks.

`ClientResponse cypherResponse = cypher.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, request);`